# Order by a date but return a string in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to do the following (which obviously doesn't work because I am attempting to order by a column not in a group by clause), where TransDateString is a varchar column, defined as `cast(datepart(m,TransDate) as varchar)+'-'+cast(datepart(yyyy,TransDate) as varchar)` of the TransDate (date) column.

```
SELECT c.TransDateString
        FROM #dataSet c
        GROUP BY c.TransDateString 
        ORDER BY c.TransDate asc
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is order the results by date but return only the column as the formatted string.

Here's what the data and output I'm looking for would be:

```
TransDate    |    TransDateString
2005-01-01   |    01-2005
2012-15-05   |    05-2012
2003-22-10   |    10-2003
```

Results:

```
 TransDateString   
  10-2003   
  01-2005   
  05-2012
```

Comment: `FOR XML PATH('')` and the question tagged with `mysql`??? how strange

Comment: please look here to improve question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It's part of a larger query. I edited it to just the pertinent part. The tsql part isn't really important.

Comment: if you could show some sample data and expected output,it will be helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;With cteRows As
(
SELECT c.TransDateString,
       Row_Number() Over (Partition By c.TransDateString Order By c.TransDate) RowNum
        FROM #dataSet c
)
Select TransDateString From cteRows Where RowNum = 1
```

Without CTE:

```
Select TransDateString From
(
Select c.TransDateString,
       Row_Number() Over (Partition By c.TransDateString Order By c.TransDate) RowNum
        FROM #dataSet c
) A
Where RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Is this possible without CTE?

Comment: You need some kind of subquery to assign the row numbers but it need not be cte.  I will update my answer.